# Get names for IDs in two columns in one from another table

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tElements (
  elementID    INTEGER,
  name         TEXT,
  area         TEXT,
  zone         TEXT,
  voltageLevel TEXT,
  mRID         TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tCAResults (
  timestamp          INTEGER NOT NULL,
  outageElementID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  monitoredElementID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  preOutageLoading   DOUBLE  NOT NULL,
  postOutageLoading  DOUBLE  NOT NULL
);
```

How can I create query where id's of `outageElementID` and `monitoredElementID` from table `tCAResult` would be displayed as names from table tElements?

I have been searching for a whole day but couldn't find the answer. The closest I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087065/sql-join-one-column-serving-as-id-for-two-columns-in-another-table) but can't work it out

Answer (score 1):

A simple `join` or two will do the job:

```
select tc.timestamp, oe.name as outageElement, me.name as monitoredElement
  from tCAResults tc
  join tElements oe on (oe.elementID = tc.outageELementID)
  join tElements me on (me.elementID = tc.monitoredElementID);
```